# authentication for perl(awstats)

Tags: perl, authentication

i am using awstats for my IIS7.5

I try to use forms authenrication, but it only work on the directory only( http://XXXX.com/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/ ).

However, I can go to http://XXXX.com/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?config=testsite directly without login.

I want people to to execute this (awstats.pl?config=testsite) before login.

I don't want to create a local domain for the users becasue I will have many user to using awstats in different subfoler.

The web.config in the /awstats

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name="SIPE_ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="20">
</forms>

</authentication>
<authorization>
<deny users="?" />
</authorization>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>

<handlers>

<add name="Perl" path="*.pl" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe &quot;%s&quot; %s" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="bitness64" />
</handlers>


<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />

</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```